# Hibernate/SQL add names/keys to results

Tags: sql, hibernate, grails

I'm using Grails for a web-application and have to create a database-query where I do a calculation with some values.
These values are from the table I'm selecting from AND the grails-application. The value of the calculation should also be passed to the results. The calculation itself and returning all the values are working like a charm.
The result im getting is something like that (selecting simply all columsn from the table):

```
[[19, 15, false, 49.04757, 8.37106, 1.0, 'some text', false, 0, 0.03360229674009102]]
```

well ... what i would have to do now is create objects of all results im getting. 
As it's the hibernate session I'm using to query the database I have the option to add "addEntity(className)" to the execution of the query - like this:

```
def list = sessionFactory.currentSession.createSQLQuery(query).addEntity(myClass).list()
```

Even better - I don't have to create the objects manually.
But the problem is, that I lose the information about the calculated value (the last entry in the upper code-snippet)

There are 2 ways I could imagine to accomplish this: hibernate gives me some options like addEntity(myClass) - just like I do it to create my objects - to add the value of the calculation

the other way would be to name the results within the sql-query, so i get something like this:

```
[[id:19, version:15, some_bool: false, first_double: 49.04757, second_double: 8.37106, some_floatvalue: 1.0, text: 'some text', another_bool: false, calculation_result: 0, 0.03360229674009102]]
```

Either way, I don't even know what to search for, as I'm not really familiar with both techniques.

all in all what I want is an easy an clean way to create instances/objects of my class and additionally have the result of the calculation.
If you have further ideas to accomplish this - I appreciate every hint and tipp

Even some buzzwords would help me to get this to work.

I hope I'm clear about my problem - if not tell me ;)

thanks in advance

Comment: so you want to instntiate an entity with the SQL query result? Or is there something more into it?

Comment: almost - i want to instantiate it AND want the result of the calculation (calculated during the query)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `org.hibernate.SQLQuery#addEntity` you would want to use `org.hibernate.SQLQuery#addRoot` which returns you a `org.hibernate.SQLQuery.RootReturn` which can be used to further define the result mapping.  Added in 3.6, which I am pretty sure is what Grails uses